# An application of the strong Markov property in the proof of the connection between Brownian motion and harmonic functions

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, harmonic-functions

Let $U$ be an open, connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $(B(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion with start at $x \in U$ and let $\overline{B_x(\delta)}$ be the closed ball about $x$ of radius $\delta$ that is contained in $U$. In order to get from $x$ to the boundary $\partial U$, $B(t)$ must first pass through $\partial B_x(\delta)$. I'd like to know how this can be proved rigorously. This is the gist of the problem.

More exactly, following is a theorem from chapter 3, "Harmonic functions, transience and recurrence" of Mörters and Peres's textbook [Brownian Motion](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/peres/) (to be referred to below as [M]). The theorem is listed below together with the proof given in the textbook (but not verbatim). I'm interested in a rigorous justification for the last couple of equations in the end of the proof, namely
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_x\left[E_x\left[\varphi(B(\tau))\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau < \infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}^+(\rho)\right]\right] & = E_x\left[u(B(\rho))\right] \\
& = \int_{\partial B_x(\delta)} u(y) \mu_{x,\delta}(dy)
\end{aligned}
$$

> ***Setting the stage***
>
> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_1$. Denote by $\mathbf{C}$ the set consisting of
>    all continuous functions from $[0,\infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. For
>    every $t \in [0,\infty)$, denote by $\pi_t : \mathbf{C} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ the projection on the $t$th coordinate and denote by
>    $\mathcal{B}$ the minimal $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbf{C}$ in which
>    all the $\pi_t$'s are measurable. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$
>    denote by $P_x$ the probability measure over the measurable space
>    $(\Omega := \mathbf{C}, \mathcal{F} := \mathcal{B})$ that renders the
>    stochastic process $(\pi_t)_{t \geq 0}$ a Brownian motion with start
>    at $x$. For every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and every
>    $\mathcal{B}/\textrm{Borel}$-measurable function $\varphi: \mathbf{C}
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, denote by $E_x(\varphi)$ the expectation of
>    $\varphi$ with respect to the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},
>  P_x)$, provided this expectation exists (we allow the possibility that
>    $E_x(\varphi) \in \{\pm \infty\}$).
>
> ***The Theorem***
>
> ([M] Theorem 3.8, p. 68)
>
> Suppose $U$ is a non-empty, open, connected set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
>    define $\tau$ to be the first hitting time of $U$'s boundary, i.e. $$
>  \tau := \inf \{t \geq 0 \mid : B(t) \in \partial U\} $$
>
> Let $\varphi: \partial U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable w.r.t.
>    the $\sigma$-algebra induced on $\partial U$ by
>    $\textrm{Borel}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and suppose the function $u: U
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $$ u(x) := E_x[\varphi(B(\tau))
>  \mathbb{1}_{\{\tau < \infty\}}] $$ for every $x \in U$, is locally
>    bounded, i.e. for every $x \in U$ there is some neighborhood $N$ of
>    $x$ such that $N \subseteq U$ and $u$ is bounded on $N$. In
>    particular, we suppose that the expectation on the right is
>    well-defined for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
>
> Then $u$ is a harmonic function.
>
> ***Proof***
>
> ([M] Proof of theorem 3.8, p. 68)
>
> We start with a lemma.
>
> > *Lemma* ([M] Theorem 3.2, p. 65) Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty, open and connected set and let $v : D \rightarrow
> >  \mathbb{R}$ be a locally bounded function. Then $v$ is harmonic on $D$
> >      iff $v$ has the (spherical) mean value property: For all $z \in D$ and
> >      $s \in (0,\infty)$ such that the closed ball $\overline{B_z(s)}
> >  \subseteq D$, we have: $v$ is integrable on $\partial B_z(s)$ and $$
> >  v(z) = \int_{\partial B_z(s)} v(w) \mu_{z, s}(dw) $$ where $\mu_{z,
> >  s}$ is the normalized uniform measure on the sphere $\partial B_z(s)$.
>
> Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\delta \in (0,\infty)$ be such that
>    the closed ball $\overline{B_x(r)} := \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid: |y -
>  x| \leq r\}$ is contained in $U$. Define the stopping time $\rho :=
>  \inf \{t \in (0,\infty) \mid: B(t) \neq B_x(\delta)\}$. Then the
>    strong Markov property implies that
>    $$ \begin{aligned} u(x) & =
>   E_x\left[E_x\left[\varphi(B(\tau))\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau < \infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}^+(\rho)\right]\right] \\
>  & = E_x\left[u(B(\rho))\right] \\
>  & = \int_{\partial B_x(\delta)} u(y) \mu_{x,\delta}(dy) \end{aligned}
>  $$
>    where $\mu_{x,\delta}$ is the normalized uniform measure on the sphere $\partial B_x(\delta)$. Therefore, by the lemma, $u$ is harmonic. Q.E.D.

Comment: The definition of $\rho$ should be with $B(t) \in \partial B_x(\delta)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: Why doesn't what you're asking follow from the fact that presumably they're working with a continuous version of the Brownian motion? Am I missing something?

Comment: It follows from the strong Markov property, once you establish that $\rho \leq \tau$. This, as Kai points out, follows from the fact that we have continuous paths.

Comment: @KaiSikorski: Yes, but *how* does it follow from this fact? What would the rigorous derivation look like?

Comment: @thomas: Yes, but *how* does it follow from this fact? What would the rigorous derivation look like?

Comment: Just the part you're asking about might not even need continuity. The set you're picking rho from includes the set you're picking tau from and you're picking an infimum.. (I assume the not equal should be a not in)

Comment: @KaiSikorski: Thank you. Would you be so kind as to write an answer to my question with a rigorous derivation of these two equations? It is not with the intuition, but rather with the formal derivation, that I'm having a hard time with.

Comment: There are several equivalent ways to state the strong Markov property, so it would help if you'd give the precise statement that your book uses.

Comment: @NateEldredge: According to [M] theorem 2.16, p. 43, "For every almost surely finite stopping time $T$, the process $(B(T+t)-B(T):t\geq0)$ is a standard Brownian motion independent of $\mathcal{F}^+(T)$."

Answer (score 2):

Taken for granted that $\rho \leq \tau$, let us see why the derivation you gave makes sense. Recall the equation chain:

$$ \begin{aligned} u(x) & \stackrel{A}{=}
  E_x\left[E_x\left[\varphi(B(\tau))\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau < \infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}^+(\rho)\right]\right] \\
 & \stackrel{B}{=} E_x\left[u(B(\rho))\right] \\
 & \stackrel{C}{=} \int_{\partial B_x(\delta)} u(y) \mu_{x,\delta}(dy)  \, .\end{aligned}
 $$

$A$: this is the definition of $u$ and a property of conditional expectation.

$B$: this is the strong Markov property and the definition of $u$, a bit more explicit:

I take some notation from the book of Revuz and Yor (Sections I.3 and III.3).
Define for $x \in E^{\mathbb{R}_+}$ and $ t\geq 0$ the translation operator $\theta_t: \, E^{\mathbb{R}_+} \to E^{\mathbb{R}_+}, \, x \mapsto \theta_t(x)$ with $(\theta_t(x))(s)= x(t+s)$. Define $\tau \circ \theta_t = \inf \{ s \geq 0 : \, B(s+t) \in \partial U\}$ and set $\theta_T(\omega) = \theta_t(\omega)$ if $T(\omega) = t$ for a stopping time $T$.
For the stopping times $\rho$ and $\tau$ it is true that
$$ \tau = \rho + \tau \circ \theta_\rho \, , $$
since $\rho \leq \tau$.
\begin{align} E_x\left[\varphi(B(\tau))\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau < \infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}^+(\rho)\right] & = E_x\left[\varphi(B(\rho + \tau \circ \theta_\rho))\mathbb{1}_{\{\rho + \tau \circ \theta_\rho < \infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}^+(\rho)\right] \\
& = E_{B(\rho)} \left[ \varphi(B(\tau)) \mathbb{1}(\tau < \infty) \right] \\
& = u(B(\rho)) \, .
\end{align}

$C$: The distribution of Browian motion started at $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ hitting the sphere $\partial B_x(\delta) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^d: \, |y| = 1\}$ is uniform: $P_x(B(\rho) \in dy) = \mu_{x,\delta}(dy)$.

Regarding $\rho \leq \tau$ (if $\rho = \inf \{ t\geq 0: \, B(t) \in \partial B_x(\delta)\}$): We take a single path $X \in \mathbf{C}$ with $X(0)=x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and show $\rho \leq \tau$ pathwise. If $\tau = \infty$, there is nothing to show. So we can assume that $X(t) \in \partial U$ for some $\tau = t>0$.

Let $t' = \sup \{ s\geq 0:\, X(s) \in |x-X(s)|<\delta \}$ and $t'' = \inf \{s\geq t':\, |x-X(s)|>\delta\}$. Clearly, $t'\leq t''$. Since the modulus is continuous we know that $s \mapsto d(s) = |x-X(s)|$ is continuous. We have $d(t')\leq \delta$ since there is a sequence $s_n \to t'$ non-decreasing with $d(s_n)<\delta$. Similarly $d(t'')\geq \delta$. If $t'=t''$ we are done, otherwise note that for $r \in (t',t'')$ we can neither have $d(r)<\delta$, nor $d(r)>\delta$, also leading to $d(r) = \delta$. In both cases we conclude that there is a $r = \rho\leq t$ with $X(r) \in \partial B_x(\delta)$. But this says that for this particular path $\rho \leq \tau$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's exactly what I wanted. I've only read the first part of your proof so far.  I'll read the second one tomorrow. However, there's an important point in the first part that I don't quite get. Would you mind elaborate on the justification for the equation $E_x\left[\varphi(B(\rho + \tau \circ \theta_\rho))\mathbb{1}_{\{\rho + \tau \circ \theta_\rho < \infty\}} \mid \mathcal{F}^+(\rho)\right] = E_{B(\rho)} \left[ \varphi(B(\tau)) \mathbb{1}(\tau < \infty) \right]$?

Comment: This equation is really, what is called "strong Markov property", see page 102 in Revuz and Yor's book (1999). In their notation $Z(\omega) = \phi(\omega(\tau(\omega)))$, where $\omega \in \mathbf{C}$ (I leave out the indicator, it's the same idea). Recall the definition of $\theta_t$ from above, $\theta_t(\omega')=(\omega'(s+t))_{s\geq 0}$. Then,
$$ Z \circ \theta_t (\omega') = Z(\theta_t(\omega')) = \phi\left(\theta_t(\omega') (\tau \circ \theta_t(\omega'))\right) = \phi \left( \omega'(t + \tau \circ \theta_t) \right) . $$

Comment: For the book see also: http://books.google.de/books?id=1ml95FLM5koC&lpg=PA102&hl=de&pg=PA102#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Thank you, thomas. I wasn't familiar with the Strong Markov property in this form. Now step B makes perfect sense. As for step C, it seems very intuitive to me that if you start a Brownian motion at the center of a finite, non-degenerate ball, the distribution of the point of impact at the time the motion hits the ball's surface will be uniform across the sphere. But how can this fact be proved formally?

Answer (score 1):

Given a ball $\bar B_r(x)\subset D$,  consider the stopping time: 
$$\tau = \min\{t\geq 0;~ x+B_t\not\in B_r(x)\}$$ 
and also for each $z\in D$ let $\tau_z = \min\{t\geq 0;~ z+B_t\not\in
D\}$. We introduce two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ on the
probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ on which the
standard Brownian motion $\{B_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is defined. The first
random variable is simply: $X_1=x+B_{\tau}$, taking values in the
measurable space $(D, \mathcal{F}_1)$ with the usual $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathcal{F}_1$ of Borel subsets of $D$.

The second random variable $X_2$ is given by the paths of $B_{\tau+t} -
B_\tau$, almost surely belonging to $E_0=C[0,\infty),
\mathbb{R}^n)$. We make $E_0$ a measurable space by equipping it with
the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(E_0)$ of its Borel subsets with
respect to the topology of uniform convergence on compact
intervals. In fact, $X_2$ takes values in a measurable subset $E$ of
$E_0$, consisting of these $f\in E$ which satisfy:
$f(0)=0$ and $|f(T)|>\mbox{diam} \, D$ for some $T>0$. We name
$\mathcal{F}_2$ the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(E_0)$ restricted to $E$.

Checking the measurability property of $E$ in $E_0$, as well as
measurability of $X_2$ with respect to $(E,\mathcal{F}_2)$ relies on
observing that $\mathcal{B}(E_0)$ is generated by the countable family
of sets of the type $A_{g,T,r} = \{f\in E_0;~
\|f-g\|_{L^\infty[0,T]}\leq r\}$, where $g$ are polynomials with
rational coefficients, and $T,r>0$ are rationals.

Now, the crucial observation is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are
independent. Indeed, $X_1$ is clearly $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-measurable,
whereas $X_2$ is $\mathcal{F}_\tau$-independent. This last statement
is a direct consequence of the strong Markov property for the shifted
Brownian motion $\{B_{\tau+t} - B_\tau\}_{t\geq 0}$ and can be checked
directly on the preimages of sets $A_{g,T,r}$.

We call $\mu_1$ the push-forward measure of $\mathbb{P}$ via $X_1$
and $\mu_2$ the push-forward of $\mathbb{P}$ via $X_2$.
Thus $(D,\mathcal{F}_1,\mu_1)$ and $(E,\mathcal{F}_2,\mu_2)$ 
are two probability spaces, and the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$
  is equivalent to the product $\mu_1\times
\mu_2$ equaling the push-forward of $\mathbb{P}$ on $D\times E$
via $(X_1, X_2)$.

Finally, consider the following random variable on $D\times E$, valued in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$F(z,f) = \varphi\big(z+f(\min\{t\geq 0;~ z+f(t)\not\in D\})\big).$$
We write:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
u(x) & = \mathbb{E}[\varphi(x+B_{\tau_x}] = \mathbb{E}[F\circ (X_1,
X_2)] = \int_{D\times E} F \;d(\mu_1\times\mu_2) \\ & = 
\int_D\int_E F(z,f)\;d\mu_2(f) \;d\mu_1(z)=\int_D \mathbb{E}[F(z,X_2)]\;d\mu_1(z),
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where we simply used Fubini's theorem. In conclusion:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split} 
u(x) & = \int_D \varphi(z+B_{\tau_z}) \;d\mu_1(z) = \int_D u(z)
\;d\mu_1(z) \\ & = \mathbb{E}[u\circ X_1] = \mathbb{E}[u(x+B_{\tau})], 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
as claimed.